# How Can I remove or hide Selenium-Selenide logs of server console

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I have a problem with logs in server console with selenide(Selenium) because, in the console is printing A lot of logs like this `12:43:05.743 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec - Connection discarded`. I need to delete or hide all logs that start with Forwarding

I have tried excluded lybraries like this.

```
excludeDependencies ++= Seq( "commons-logging" % "commons-logging",
  "org.slf4" % "slf4j-simple")
```

This line is a SBT CODE.

I have also tried this

```
   ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    webDriver.setLogLevel(Level.OFF);
    WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(webDriver);
```

But de server log is the same.

A part of log is this:

```
12:43:05.634 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
12:43:05.634 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 1][route: {}->http://localhost:18640] can be kept alive indefinitely
12:43:05.634 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: set socket timeout to 0
12:43:05.634 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 1][route: {}->http://localhost:18640][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2000; total allocated: 1 of 2000]
May 28, 2019 12:43:05 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver log
OFF: Executed: [9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f, findElement {using=css selector, value=#submitButton}]
May 28, 2019 12:43:05 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver log
OFF: Executing: findElement [9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f, findElement {using=css selector, value=#submitButton}]
12:43:05.740 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
12:43:05.740 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
12:43:05.740 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {}->http://localhost:18640][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2000; total allocated: 1 of 2000]
12:43:05.740 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 1][route: {}->http://localhost:18640][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2000; total allocated: 1 of 2000]
12:43:05.740 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: set socket timeout to 0
12:43:05.740 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec - Stale connection check
^C12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: set socket timeout to 10800000
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec - Executing request POST /session/9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f/element HTTP/1.1
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.headers - http-outgoing-1 >> POST /session/9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f/element HTTP/1.1
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Length: 48
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Host: localhost:18640
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.headers - http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.6 (Java/1.8.0_212)
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "POST /session/9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f/element HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Length: 48[\r][\n]"
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "Host: localhost:18640[\r][\n]"
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.6 (Java/1.8.0_212)[\r][\n]"
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
12:43:05.741 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "{"using":"css selector","value":"#submitButton"}"
12:43:05.743 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[read] I/O error: Connection reset"
12:43:05.743 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: Close connection
12:43:05.743 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: Shutdown connection
12:43:05.743 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.e.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
12:43:05.743 [Forwarding findElement on session 9d20bbba59cf6ad720500943a378f26f to remote] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 1][route: {}->http://localhost:18640][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2000; total allocated: 0 of 2000]
```

And only I want to hide, anything that start with Forwarding